# Find if a string from one field is contained in another field on the same row and delete it if so

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following fields in each row

```
Make      Model
Toyota    Toyota Camry
```

I need a query that will check if the string in Make is also contained in Model and delete the portion of Model value that matches.

Comment: Please provide your table structure with expected results...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for with `replace`:

```
update yourtable 
set model = replace(model, make, '');
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58bd6c/1)

Comment: Cheers. Any way to remove the whitespace that occurs after the make string is deleted from model. Like maybe replace(model + ' ', make, ''), I ran the query however, so now the space is just the first character of the field.

Comment: @LaserBeak -- sure, `trim` would probably be the easiest bet... `set model = trim(replace(...))`